# how to generate table dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to generate a number from `1` to `70` in a table with each row containing only 5 numbers. I have generated this but I don't know how to close the table row after the fifth `</td>`. I also want it to generate an `<a>` tag. Please help me.

```js
flag = false;
for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  if (!flag) {
    $("tbody").append("<tr>")
    flag = true;
  }

  $('tr').append('<td><a data-index=' + i + '>' + i + '</a></td>');

  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    $("td:nth-child(5n)").insertAfter('</tr>');
    flag = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
    <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>
    <table class="table table-bordered location">
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Well, for one, you're appending the same `td` to every `tr` on the page on every loop iteration. You should create the elements you need up-front, then do a final insertion when everything is ready.

Comment: Waleed Khan you have asked for a solution and there are 2 solutions provided.. Please take time to revert back if any solution works for you.. Appreciate people's effort in helping you..

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use jQuery append code like this:

```
$('tbody').append(
   $('<tr>').append(
     $('td').append(
       $('a').attr('data-index', i)
      )
    )
 )
```

And jQuery will automatically close tags for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small logic change. Idea is to build all the `td` tags in a variable and when you reach a number multiple by 5 then append it to the `tbody` by wrapping it around a `tr`

```js
var $tableBody = $('tbody'); // use a Id selector here
var rowHTML = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  rowHTML += '<td><a data-index=' + i + '>' + i + '</a></td>';

  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    $tableBody.append('<tr>' + rowHTML + '</tr>');
    rowHTML = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
    <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>
    <table class="table table-bordered location">
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```